# latex/tabular - How to have all \parboxes coming from p-columns in the same table-row having same height/depth?

Tags: tables, columns

I try to understand `p`-column-type.

You can specify width of `\parbox`es coming from `p`-columns by the argument of the column-specifier `p`.

Seems each of these boxes has its own height and depth.
Otherwise `\vfill` in the first column of the first table would have the effect of shifting the last `m` in that column downwards.

Is a column-type feasible where all `\parboxes` created by that column-type within the same table-row get the same height and depth, i.e., of the highest/deepest box in that row? So that one could, e.g., use `\vfill` to get the a result that looks the same as the second table?

(The focus of the question is not on `\vfill` but is on getting `\parbox`es into a table row automatically that have same vertical measurements as the otherwise vertically highest/deepest box within that row.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{m}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\wd\mybox}|p{\wd\mybox}|}
\hline 
m \par m \par \vfill m & m m m m m m m m m m\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{tabular}{|p{\wd\mybox}|p{\wd\mybox}|}
\hline 
m 
m
\phantom{m}
\phantom{m}
\phantom{m}
\phantom{m}
\phantom{m}
\phantom{m}
\phantom{m}
m
& m m m m m m m m m m\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill\hfill\hfill\null
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `l` columns and nest  a `\parbox` so you can use the optional height argument

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How to get height/depth of table-row's largest `\parbox` automatically for the otherwise smaller `\parbox`es in the row?

Comment: well it would be easiest if you knew in advance, or measure each box and write the max size of each row to the aux file and fix on the next run or ....

Comment: rather than `\vfill m` can't you put `m` in the next row of the table?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't ask you to implement it for me, I only ask for judgement: Is a column-type feasible at all that does the measurements for me on a table-row-basis and that probably incorporates `\multicolumn` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this MWE of course.  Real life purpose is a different thing. ;-)

Comment: but it may be that your real life case is best implemented that way, perhaps with negative space so it looks like a single row.

Comment: a default latex tabular sets each cell before reading later cells so it can not easily know the deepest entry, so you need to abuse the next row to get that or use  a table mechanism that does have more information, perhaps `tabularray`